# profile management in MEAN stack

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I'm seeking for a profile management template based on MEAN stack.

My main target is to implement data editing authorization (so that every user can just edit their own profile data and view others).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [passport](http://passportjs.org/). Also take a look at angular-fullstack generator [here](http://tylerhenkel.com/introducing-yeoman-angularjs-express-full-stack-generator/). It comes with authorisation also.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Mean.io. its a pretty good starting place for the mean stack. You can then pull in things you might need to improve https://github.com/linnovate/mean

Comment: of course i've checked that. I need a working example because I have not enough experiment to start from a blank project.

Answer (score 0):

There are bunch of mean stack CRUD examples on Google. In fact, many amazing ones. Type mean stack crud tutorial in google and you ll be good to go :0).